# Will Apple approve custom keyboard app which will work only after allow full Access?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, custom-keyboard

I have noticed that Apple rejecting custom keyboard app if its doesn't have any feature which will work if `Allow Full Access` toggle is **FALSE**.

But I wanted to implement extension keyboard which will work only after `Allow Full Access` toggle is **TRUE** in device settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, and if they do you risk being denied in the future.

Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) section **4.4** requires compliance to the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214) and additionally, for Keyboard extensions section **4.4.1** states:

Extensions must:

> - Remain functional without full network access
> - Collect user activity only to enhance the functionality of the user’s keyboard extension on the iOS device.

Extensions must not:

> - Include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases;

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have one doubt, we can't even do In-App purchase/Apple pay in extension keyboard?

Comment: I suggest if you're looking for a possible business models around keyboard extensions, take a look at how other iOS Keyboard apps are marketed, what they cost and what functionality they have within the extension and containing iOS app.

Comment: i have 7 version uploaded and 8th version rejected with same issue i am not getting how previous approved by apple review team.